# Google GMSGeocoder always gives me null sublocality

Tags: ios, google-geocoder

I am currently developing an IOS app to reverse geocode coordinates using google maps geocoding library, specifically using GMSGeocoder class, 
I always get locality and street name, but the sublocality is always null, But when I use android geocoder class the sublocality is not null for the same coordinates and also when I use google geocoding api , the sublocality is not null. I also tried using Apple's geocoding class CLGeocoder and also It is null. Any help would be appreciated , Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Google Maps iOS SDK.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78809393#comment17

Google says fixed but it is not.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78809393#comment24

I have added coordinates that i have issue with. You may also add.
if they fix it then our issue will be fixed too.

In meantime, i have added a workaround in my app to use locality if subLocality is nil. This may not be desired by you but i am fine with displaying locality ie city till the time issue is fixed by Google.

Hope this helps.
Ashish

Comment: @khalid-shadid Please test your code now. Google has fixed the issue. Please read comment https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110604823#comment3